# Django migrate work on local but not on Elastic Beanstalk production

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, django-migrations, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm working on a django project that has been live for months. No changes to the settings file or the environment itself.

I recently added a field to a model, however when I deploy it to my Amazon Elastic Beanstalk environenment, it fails to migrate the changes to the database. I get the following error message:

```
Synchronizing apps without migrations:
    Creating tables...
        Running deferred SQL...
    Installing custom SQL...
Running migrations:
    No migrations to apply.
    Your models have changes that are not yet reflected in a migration, and so won't be applied.
    Run 'manage.py makemigrations' to make new migrations, and then re-run 'manage.py migrate' to apply them.
```

Now the error message might sound pretty obvious, but thing is that I made a copy of the database from the production server to my local database server and tried the `migrate` command again, Voila works on local. No error message regarding models being changed.

When I run `makemigrations` I get `No changes detected.`. I also tried `makemigrations <app>` for every single app in my project. Still says `No changes detected`.

**So as a summary:**

I've made changes to a model, I made new migrations of it, I tried to migrate it on production server and result was error. I tried on local server with an exact copy of the database, and it works fine.

Ideas?

EDIT:

It seems like this have something to do with `ImageField`. The field I added to my model was a `ImageField`, but when I removed it, and then tested adding both `CharField` and `FileField` the migration worked fine.

When I then modified the `FileField` and made it into a `ImageField` the `migrate` error returned.

Very confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this problem by completely rebuilding my environment at Amazon and importing my local version of the database to the new RDS/MYSQL instance.

This is not a "proper" solution since it does not actually find out why this was happening. I synced and resynced my database dozens of times. I went back to a migration file that successfully synced, but as soon as I added my `ImageField` to my model again I got the same error when I tried to `manage.py migrate`.

After rebuilding the environment migrations work again.